# SQLITE select substring with numbers

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite, select

DB: SQLITE

I have column like this:

```
col1
-----------------------
sadGDd asd : 342,45 sdSf
sdlkjk k k30 234.34  ss
sdfkHHkdsf 3422
```

i need select **substring**

```
substr(col1)
---------
342,45
234.34
3422
```

Comment: Why dont you save your Integer in other column?

Comment: Data from ocr, I ll save integers in other column, but how can i select them?

Comment: I would handle it in function (java/php/etc) then insert into my database.

Comment: Thank you! I ll try it with python

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
WHERE x REGEXP '\b[\d,.]+\b'
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAEoVw/1)

Comment: Thank you! But i need select substring, not a string

Answer (score 0):

Aleks took nice answer, but his regexp match expression like 123.456,789.1011,1516.1718

I think this is better to use:

```
   \b[\d]+[.,][\d]+\b
```